# wsgi, xampp and windows

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, xampp, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to setup wsgi on xampp in order to run python web applications.

I've downloaded the appropriate binary from [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) and i've installed the module as described. As I'm running xampp, my module is located at `C:\xampp\apache\modules`. I've also renamed the module (as suggested) to `mod_wsgi.so`.

I've installed the module by adding the following to my httpd.conf:

`LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`

immediately underneath all of the other module imports. However, whenever I attempt to restart xampp, it wont start up again. The error I get is the endlessly helpful:

> The Apache2.2 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function..

It should be noted that if I comment out the `LoadModule...` line above, my server restarts without issue. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The precompiled modules on mod_wsgi site are for 32 bit. You cannot use a 64 bit version of either Apache or Python. Further, Python must be installed for all users and not just the user it was installed with. See if any of those are the problem.